# Get email subject and sender using imaplib?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am getting the following response after executing the code shown below the response. How can I parse through this response to get the sender (John Smith) and the subject (test)?

```
[('13010 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)] {57}', 'From: John Smith <jsmith@gmail.com>\r\nSubject: test\r\n\r\n'), ')']
```

-

```
conn.fetch(message, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703185/using-email-headerparser-with-imaplib-fetch-in-python) will help. Try something like this:

```
from email.parser import HeaderParser
data = conn.fetch(message, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')
header_data = data[1][0][1]
parser = HeaderParser()
msg = parser.parsestr(header_data)
```

and then `msg` should be a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this to fetch the header information of all the mails.

```
import imaplib
import email

obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
obj.login('username', 'password')
obj.select('folder_name')
resp, data = obj.uid('FETCH', ','.join(map(str,uidl_list)) , '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From Subject)] RFC822.SIZE)')
```

**Note: Here 'uidl_list' is the list of uid of mails whose subject u want.**